# Change dynamically selected value with typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, select

Hi I've this piece of code:

```
<div>
    <div *ngIf="!showInfo">
      <div >
          <br>    
<table style="border: 0px; display: table; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; width: 155%;">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th style="color: black;border: 0px;">Type</th>
                    <th style="color: black;border: 0px;">Radius</th>
                    <th style="color: black;border: 0px;">Number</th>
                  </tr>
                  <br>
                  <tr *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index">
                    <td style=" border: 0px;" >
                      <input #focus matInput type='text' style=" border: 0px;"  type="text" value="{{row.type}}" readonly  [(ngModel)]="row.type" >
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <select (change)="changeRadius($event, i)" attr.id="{{row.id}}" [value]="5000">
                        <option *ngFor="let meters of radius"  [value]="meters.value">{{meters.value}}</option>
                      </select>
                    </td>
                    <td style="margin-left: 60px; border: 0px;">
                      <input  matInput type='text' style="margin-left: 30px; border: 0px;" readonly  type="text" value="{{row.number}}" [(ngModel)]="row.number">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            <hr style="color: darkred;" >

            <div>
              <button mat-button class="custom-button" (click)="getNewRadius()">
                  OK
              </button>
```

The first time that this table appear I want that every select has like selected option 5000, so the user select the new radius for each select and click on OK. In my typescript I have an array "radiousToSend" that contain the selected radious for each select.Now I want that every time that this table appear has like selected option the value that user choose the last time that is the value inside "radiousToSend"

I tried to do something like this:

```
let pan = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('1'));
    pan[0].options[pan[0].options.selectedIndex].selected = true;
```

but it doesn't work because every time that this table appears every select has as selected value=5000 but i want that only the first time this value is static.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Maybe a stackblitz link would help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two-way binding with the `ngModel` directive to bind to a variable in the controller.

Template

```html
<select (change)="changeRadius($event, i)" attr.id="{{row.id}}" [(ngModel)]="selectOption">
  <option *ngFor="let meters of radius" [value]="meters.value">{{meters.value}}</option>
</select>
```

And set the value of `selectOption` variable  in the click event handler.

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  selectOption = 5000;   // <-- default value of all select options

  getNewRadius() {    // <-- change all options to 1000 on button click
    this.selectOption = 1000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think that is not my case, because when user click Ok I'll have 7 select and an array with 7 values. I would that the other times that this table appear every select has like selected option, the respective values that is inside this array.

Comment: Could you please update the question with use case scenarios. I don't quite understand what you want.

Comment: yes, I hope that now is more easy to understand, I want that the first select has like selected option the first element that is in "radiusToSend", the second select has like selected option the second element that is in "radiusToSend" etc etc